# How is a morphism between projective curves the union of morphisms of affine curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I am reading a paper, and it uses the following definition:

> A morphism ${f : C \to C'}$ of affine curves is the restriction to C
> of a map of the following form, where ${f_1}$ and ${f_2}$ are elements of ${k[x,y].}$
> $${\mathbb{A}^2(k) \to \mathbb{A}^2(k)}$$ $${(x,y)\mapsto (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))}$$
> If $C$ and ${C'}$ are projective curves, then a map ${f : C \to C'}$ is a morphism if and only if ${C = \bigcup_{i \in I}C_i}$ and ${C' = \bigcup_{j \in J}C'_j}$ for finite sets $I$ and $J$ and open subsets ${C_i,C_j'}$, which are affine curves, such that for all ${i \in I}$, ${f(C_i)\subseteq C_j'}$ for some ${j \in J}$ and ${f|_{C_i}}$ is a morphism of affine curves.

I am very much confused by this definition. Can anyone give an example?

Comment: As an analogy, do you know what manifolds are? What is a smooth map between manifolds?

Comment: projective spaces are glued together by affine patches. And on an affine chart, it looks like a morphism between affine curves.

Comment: @Sisi I know that P^n can be viewed as n+1 copies of A^n; does it mean when you view the curve on these copies of affine space it looks like an affine morphism? If this is the case, I'm a little confused about the "open" part. For instance if the projective curve is yz - x^3 = 0, on one chart it is the set {[x:x^3:1]}; how is this a Zariski open set in P^2?

Comment: First question: yes you can view as an affine morphism. Second question. $yz-x^3$ is not homogenous? projective curves should be defined my homogenous equations

Comment: @Sisi Apologies, yes. I meant yz^2 - x^3 = 0. Although on one chart the affine curve is still {[x:x^3:1]} and I'm still struggling to see why this is Zariski open

Comment: I put this as a post. your set defined by $[x:x^3:1]$ is not an affine open in $\mathbf{P}^2$, its some kind of 1-parameter family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought its getting too lengthy in the comments:
Your question boils down to the fact that you consider a morphism of projective curves $C \rightarrow C'$ on open affines in the projective space.
I.e. if $C \subset \mathbf{P}^2$ is a projective curve defined by maybe $YZ^2-X^3=0$ then note that $\mathbf{P}^2$ is covered by three affine charts $U_x,U_y,U_z$ corresponding to the opens where the coordinates $X,Y,Z$ are invertible.
Then $U_x$ is $\mathbf{Spec}(k[Y/X,Z/X])$ and $C \cap U_x$ is defined by $yz^2-1=0$ (affine curve, something you can draw on a sheet of paper), where you set $Y/X=:y$ and $Z/X=:z$. That is one affine patch and the others analogously.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes sense to me. Do you know why the author referred to C_i and C_j' then as open? Since from what I can tell the affine curves C_i will not be open in P^n

Comment: good question: they are open in $C$ but not in $\mathbf{P}^2$!

Comment: Ohhhhhhh. As in ${C_i}$ is open under the subspace topology on ${C}$? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but how is this so? As in, how can we write ${C_i = C \cap U}$ for some open ${U \subset P^n}$? Thank you!

Comment: its open by definition of the subspace topology on $C$: $C'\subset C$ is open in $C$ if $C'=C\cap U$ for some open $U$ in $\mathbf{P}^2$.

Comment: I understand yes, what exactly would $U$ be here?

Comment: $U=U_x$ just $Spec$ of a polynomial ring in 2 variables, so just the affine plane. Its on open affine chart of $\mathbf{P}^2$. $C'$ is then an affine plane curve

Comment: Ahhhhh right of course yes. If you take the affine plane ${U := \{[1:y:z]\}}$ then the complement of that ${U^c}$ is when ${x=0}$, i.e. ${V(x)}$ which is an algebraic set in ${\mathbb{P}^2}$. And so $U$ is open and ${C' = C\cap U}$ is obviously open in $C$ as part of the subspace topology. Thank you so much I think I get this now, I was confused because I thought the definition was saying ${C'}$ was open in ${\mathbb{P}^2}$ which clearly won't be true